# Prove that the Legendre polynomial recurrence relationship satisfies the defining differential equation

Tags: polynomials, approximation, computational-mathematics, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to show that from this recurrent relationship
$$ (n+1)P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1)xP_n(x) - nP_{n-1}(x) $$
that the Legendre polynomial $P_n(x)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$ (1-x^2)P'' - 2xP' + n(n+1)P = 0 $$

I can show both equations from the corresponding generating function but am not quite sure how to show from the recurrent relationship that the differential equation holds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Use induction to prove that Legendre polynomials solve the corresponding differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060232/use-induction-to-prove-that-legendre-polynomials-solve-the-corresponding-differe/1067596#1067596)

Although, as mentioned there, I used 3 recurrence relationships, not one (copied below).

$$P_{n+1}^{'} -P_{n-1}^{'} = (2n+1)P_n$$

$$(n+1)P_{n+1} = (2n+1)xP_n -nP_{n-1}$$

$$P_{n+1}-P_{n-1} = (x^2-1)\cdot \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\cdot P_n^{'}$$

I guess that one of these three can be derived from the other two, but I think not that the top and bottom one can both be derived from the middle one - but feel free to give it a try :-).